# Is it possible to reopen a closed branch in Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial

I understand that it is possible to close a named branch in Mercurial, so that it will not appear in the `hg branches` list:

```
hg commit --close-branch -m 'close badbranch, this approach never worked'
```

Is it possible to later re-open the branch if need be?

Comment: You should simply try it, the best way to learn is to experiment, and since repositories are cheap with Hg, just go wild.

Comment: Dirty little secret: a "branch" in Hg speak is just another way of saying "a text label associated with a commit". A "branch" can have many different heads to many different commits that are not related.

Answer (score 165, accepted):

You can just `hg update` to the closed branch then do another `hg commit` and it will automatically reopen.

The `closed` flag is just used to filter out closed branches from `hg branches` and `hg heads` unless you use the `--closed` option - it doesn't prevent you from using the branches.

Comment: The commit won't do anything unless there is something to actually commit, so you may need to make a gratuitous change to make it happen.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out - I'd assumed that changes were implied by doing a commit, but of course if you simply want to remove the closed flag you can't without a change.

Comment: A tag is sufficient to make it commitable.

Comment: This may work from the command line interface, I haven't tried it yet, but TortoiseHg won't let you update to a closed branch. If you try to do so, the Update button is disabled.To get this to work I had to update to the branch before the close changeset (effectively the parent) and then update to the close changeset. Odd thing is, when you update to the parent, TortoiseHg claims the close changeset (the descendant) is the parent. Whatever, it works just fine once you jump through the proper hoops.

Comment: Used it (command line via terminal in phpstorm) and works like a charm, thanks

Answer (score 15):

> You can reopen a branch by using the "-f" flag when 'creating' the branch.

No, this command will create a new branch with the same name.

Just forget that it's closed. Switch to the branch, make the changes and commit. It will be automatically reopened. When you're done you can close it again.

Comment: I thought that, unlike Git, Mercurial named branches are permanent, and that branch names therefore can't be re-used. What am I confusing? Is it multiple heads for the same branch that we're talking about?

Answer (score 2):

try with following:

```
hg pull && hg update branch_name
```

Now make a small change to one of the file and then commit it

```
 hg commit -m "minor change"
```

then push it

```
hg push -b .
```

Now you should be able to work normally.

Answer (score -3):

Try this.

Switch to the closed branch before executing. ( hg up closed_branch )

hg st

touch a

add a

hg commit -m 'reopening the closed branch'

This will reopen the closed branch.

Comment: This is adding a useless empty file to the repository, it's wrong.