# Reopen Closed Branch

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I'm using Mercurial with  TortoiseHG Workbench. I closed a branch by accident. I tried updating to it and making a commit to see if it would reopen (since there didn't appear to be an option to reopen the branch)

I was able to make a commit and push, but on TortoiseHG, it still says that the Head is Closed!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Option to reopen branch doesn't exist, because **commit on top** of closed head effectively **open** this head (and commited head *must not be "closed"*: it's metadata from previous changeset): test this with `hg branches` and|or `hg heads`

Additional reading:

- [Is it possible to reopen a closed branch in Mercurial?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4099345/is-it-possible-to-reopen-a-closed-branch-in-mercurial)
- [New changesets on a closed branch that must make it to default](http://mercurial.808500.n3.nabble.com/New-changesets-on-a-closed-branch-that-must-make-it-to-default-td3772174.html)

Answer (score 1):

I found out what happened.

On TortoiseHG, I clicked the Branch: button to close a branch. When I updated to my correct branch, I noticed that I forgot to check that the button does not say "close current branch".

A simple commit should solve this problem