# SourceTree Windows Mercurial - reopen closed branch

Tags: windows, mercurial, atlassian-sourcetree

When I try to reopen a closed branch I get an error saying:

hg branch -y branchname
abort: a branch of the same name already exists

(use 'hg update' to switch to it)

Completed with errors, see above.

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4099345/is-it-possible-to-reopen-a-closed-branch-in-mercurial

Comment: was asking to see if there is a way to do this through the SourceTree interface

Comment: Personally I use TortoiseHg, but I imagine SourceTree would have to prominently present both "update" and "commit" options...

Answer (score 6):

To reopen a closed branch you use hg update instead of hg branch. Just use `hg update branchname` then next time you commit the branch will be marked as open.